# ECS OutOfMemory when processing large object

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory, amazon-ecs

I'm encountering a memory-related problem with my ECS Fargate service while processing messages from an SQS queue. Recently, when dealing with a particularly large object, multiple containers terminated with the error "Terminating due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space." These messages were subsequently sent to a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ). Despite checking CloudWatch logs, I couldn't pinpoint the exact location of the exception in the code.

The container memory limit was set to 10,240 MiB. Given that the container memory is set to 10,240 MiB and the object size is 240 MB, even parallel processing should not exhaust this memory. Therefore, I suspect the issue might be related to the Java heap memory, prompting the consideration of increasing the heap size.

```
const cpu = new monocdk_1.CfnParameter(this, 'cpu', {
    type: 'Number',
    default: 2048,
    description: "The number of CPU units used by the container. More details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-cpu-memory-error.html)."
});

const memoryLimitMiB = new monocdk_1.CfnParameter(this, 'memoryLimitMiB', {
    type: 'Number',
    default: 10240,
    description: "The amount (in MiB) of memory used by the container. More details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-cpu-memory-error.html)."
});
```

I'm contemplating increasing the Java heap memory with the Xmx setting. Currently it is set to 256M

`<jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>`

Is increasing the Java heap memory a reasonable approach to address this OutOfMemoryError issue? If not, any suggestions on alternative solutions or areas to investigate further would be greatly appreciated.